# C# Selenium Webdriver Errors when clicking on a table cell

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

Hi I'm having trouble clicking on some elements when I'm writing my automation tests. Frustrating as it seems to work when I step through the code but not when I let it just run through in debug. I'm fairly new to selenium so any advice is welcomed.

This is the grid/table I'm looking at. [Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQMZb.png)

And this is the HTML for the table body.

```html
<tbody>
  <tr data-id="471892">
    <td class="checkbox"><span class="checkbox" data-id="471892"></span></td>
    <td class="left" data-edit="false"><a href="/Contacts/Contact/471892">Contact1, Test</a></td>
    <td class="left" data-edit="false"><a href="/Contacts/Account/258144">Dan Test 1</a></td>
    <td class="left" data-edit="true" data-editid="280122">Automation Tester</td>
    <td class="left" data-edit="true"></td>
    <td class="left" data-edit="true">1234567890</td>
    <td class="left" data-edit="true">07123456789</td>
    <td class="left" data-edit="true" data-fieldid="324" data-dataid="64345" data-filtertype="10">Sherratt, Rachel
      <a class="icon edit" id="grid-edit" style="display: none;"></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Trouble is, the developers have added an edit icon for each cell that moves based on which cell you hover the mouse over. So the element isn't always present & no matter what I try it doesn't seem to work.

This is the method I have.

```
    public void gridEditText(IJavaScriptExecutor jse, string text, int cell) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Browser.getDriver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15));
        IWebElement clickableElement = wait.Until(Browser.ElementIsClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='grid-main']/tbody/tr[1]/td[" + cell + "]")));
        jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", clickableElement);
        clickableElement.Click();
        //Grid Edit only appears when the mouse hovers over the cell
        IWebElement elem = wait.Until(Browser.ElementIsClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='grid-main']/tbody/tr[1]/td[" + cell + "]/a[@id='grid-edit']")));
        String js = "arguments[0].style.display='inline';";
        jse.ExecuteScript(js, elem);
        elem.Click();

        IWebElement gridEditText = wait.Until(Browser.ElementIsClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='grid-main']/tbody/tr[1]/td[" + cell + "]/input[@id='grid-edit-text']")));
        gridEditText.Clear();

        IWebElement gridEditText2 = wait.Until(Browser.ElementIsClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id='grid-main']/tbody/tr[1]/td[" + cell + "]/input[@id='grid-edit-text']")));
        gridEditText2.SendKeys(text);
    }
```

Any ideas please? 
This is one error

```
    An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

    Additional information: unknown error: Element <a class="icon edit" id="grid-edit" style="display: inline;"></a> is not clickable at point (1096, 296). Other element would receive the click:" <div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Anyone? Would really appreciate any help on this

Comment: The error message is telling you what's wrong.  There's an `<div class="overlay"></div>` that's preventing webdriver from clicking the target element.  Find that overlay and make sure it's closed/dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that there is another element (on top?) that would receive the click event. Instead of doing a Selenium .Click(), use a JavaScript .click():

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
```